# Await for the test() function to finish before executing the next one

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, testing

I'm testing multiple consecutive actions in a test group. The methods being tested are asynchronous:

```dart
void main() {
  group(
    '...',
    () async {
      test('test-A', () async {
        await asyncMethod(); // <-- async
        expect(..., true);
      });

      test('test-B', () async {
        await anotherAsyncMethod();
        expect(..., true);
      });

      // ...
    },
  );
}
```

The problem is, while I can make the function I'm passing into `test` asynchronous, I can't await for `test` itself. I need the second test to start from the state that the first one left behind, but since I can't await for `test-A` to finish, `test-B` might start running before `test-A` finished and that would cause it to fail.

I could separate those tests into separate files, but that would cause a lot of code repetition - I would have to copy the code from `test-A` into `test-B`, except without wrapping it into `test` this time.